# RATIO_TO_REPORT in real life

Tags: oracle

`RATIO_TO_REPORT` is an analytic function which returns the proportion of a value over the total set of values. A statement "`RATIO_TO_REPORT` of 2 over (1,2,3,4,5)" is (2/15) i.e. 0.133.

But when and in which situation it is useful in real life problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you split a check with your friends in a restaurant and later you want to know how many % you have paid
2. you participated in a triathlon with running/swimming/riding. Later you want to know what was a percentage of  swimming over total time.

You can do all of it manually if you have total running time or total check sum available.
But it means that this total  should be in sync with it parts.
You can just keep parts and never calculate total if you don't really need it.